# Validar sesión iniciada en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Como puedo validar el inicio de sesión, me doy cuenta que si regreso de nuevo a la pagina de inicio de sesión, me vuelve a pedir que me loguee, como puedo resolver esto?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["user_code"])) {
    if (PhpCaptcha::Validate($_POST['user_code'])) {
        $objAccountData = new AccountData();
        $objAccountData->LoadByPost();

        if ($objAccountData->FazerLogin()) {
            $_SESSION["id"]           = $objAccountData->id;
            $_SESSION["name"]         = $objAccountData->name;
            $_SESSION["access_level"] = $objAccountData->access_level;
            echo "<script>location.href='" . $kal_baseweb . "/index.php'</script>";
            exit;
        } else {
            $msg = "<div id=alert-danger><font color=red>" . $kal_errordatos . "</font></div>";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = "<div id=alert-danger><font color=red>" . $kal_errorcaptcha . "</font></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el index preguntas si ya existe un  $_SESSION["name"] redireccionas a la pagina que queres que vaya.

```
if ($_SESSION["name"]== true) {
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=pagina.php">';
}
```

Comment: estoy preguntando si existe esa variable.

Comment: @Novato00 te anduvo ?

Comment: si compañero, muchas gracias.